# VBA ActiveCell.Offset unexpected results - skipping cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting unexpected results with the code snippet below in a worksheet module.

It correctly does the "Label 5" and "Qty" cells but "Description" is placed in cell `L22` instead of `B22`

I did a `debug.print` on the line numbers at each stage and they are incrementing.  `A21` is a merged cell.  `L22` is also outside the print area of the worksheet if that matters any.

If I uncomment the `ActiveCell.Offset(lineNumber, 0).Select` it selects the correct cell of `A22` but then puts the `Qty` and `Description` into cells `A23` and `B23` which in the proper columns but wrong row.

```
Sub test()
On Error Resume Next

Dim lineNumber As Integer

lineNumber = 0

    Worksheets(1).range("A21").Select
     ActiveCell.Offset(lineNumber, 0).value = "Label 5"   'A21
     lineNumber = lineNumber + 1
     ActiveCell.Offset(lineNumber, 0).value = "Qty" 'A22
     ActiveCell.Offset(lineNumber, 1).value = "Description" 'B22 -- Prints to L22
     lineNumber = lineNumber + 1

End Sub
```

[image: offsetissue]

Comment: why do you use all these `Select` in the first place ? juse use `Range("A21").Offeset(lineNumber).Value = 'Label5"` , etc. Also, didn't understand at the end from your post which cells are merged and which are not

Comment: @Comintern added `linenumber` setting in there.

Comment: .Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset).  Were you trying to offset the column? A21 = Label 5, B22 = Qty, C22 = Description?  If so then you want to change the second element in offset, not the first.  Otherwise, I tested your code and it put A21 = Label 5, A22= Qty and B22 = Description.  There must be something else going on there.

Comment: @ShaiRado I only use one select.  I used the second one to test.  it's commented out.  The `B` column was merged to column `K` but it is not merged any more.

Comment: Do you have any other code? Can't see how anything can be put in L22.

Comment: No other code.  What you see is what I have.  Added a graphic of the output.

Comment: Check to see if you have a formula in L22 or B22.....  Is there any code at all on the sheet module?

Comment: Are rows 20 and 21 merged cells in your screenshot?

Comment: Yes, 20 and 21 are merged cells.

Comment: @JohnMuggins No formulas or code in sheet modules

Comment: Are you done editing the question?

Comment: Yes.  I took out some of the comments that were confusing others.

Comment: You edited the question.  Exactly what cells do you want each of the three elements to be in?  You said A23 and B23 were the correct columns but wrong row.  What row do you want them in?

Comment: Maibe I'm tired, you have `Worksheets(1).range("B21").Select`, then `ActiveCell.Offset(lineNumber, 0).value = "Label 5"   'A21` , how is that `A21` ? `lineNumber = 0` so your `Offset(0,0)` same cell, still `"B21"`

Comment: It's because of the merged cells in row 21.

Comment: @Rory that was it.  Unmerged the cell and it ran fine.

Comment: @ShaiRado Sorry it should have said `"A21"` it was a typo in the code but wasn't the issue.

Comment: Merged cells are best avoided, but if you needed to keep row 21 merged, use this: `ActiveCell.Offset(lineNumber).Offset(, 1).value = "Description"`

Comment: So when you said the cells were unmerged ...

Comment: @SJR tunnel vision on the part that wasn't working and forgot about the top row being merged

Comment: Easily done. I usually scratch my head the longest over the simplest things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why you shouldn't use `Active*`, `Select`, and `Offset`.  Use hard object references, {null}, and `Cells` or `Range` respectively.  You're writing a fixed layout, so just hard code it:

```
Sub test()
    With Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A21").Value = "Label 5"  `On merged ranges, just use the top left cell.
        .Range("A22").Value = "Qty"
        .Range("B22").Value = "Description"
    End With
End Sub
```

If you need to reuse this, you can pass it a row parameter for where the merged "header" cell is located:

```
Private Sub WriteHeaders(targetSheet As Worksheet, titleRow As Long, heading As String)
    With targetSheet
        .Cells(titleRow, 1).Value = heading
        .Cells(titleRow + 1, 1).Value = "Qty"
        .Cells(titleRow + 1, 2).Value = "Description"
    End With
End Sub
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
WriteHeaders Worksheets(1), 21, "Label 5"
```

Comment: Further to @Rory's comment above, you can use centre across selection for formatting rather then merging cells.

Comment: @Travis - So merge them and adjust the bottom code example to write to the appropriate cells.

Comment: Got it working.  This was part of a much larger routine so I'm going to modify this to also write the content below the headers.  Would that be an alright practice or no?

Comment: @Travis - I don't see why not - it depends on the overall structure of the rest of the code.  My personal taste would be to keep it separate, but if you're treating the content under it as a discrete block of data, go for it.  It's mainly a question of where you draw the line as to what is a "single responsibility".

Comment: I made it a separate function to handle the content.